How to import python files from parent directory
I have a file variable in my main file that is the log file I want to log to.This is in the parent directory.I want to import this, to put the errors in the log.
I tried using a relative import (from ..main import file), but this gave me an ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package. I tried using sys.path.append, but that didn't work either.

You can't import non-python files.  Do you mean you want to read the contents of the log file?

I have a file variable in my main.py file. That is in the parent directory too.

Importing only works with .py files.  You cannot import a log file.
